# Match value if other are not matched

Tags: ruby

I have this Ruby map:

```
FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE = { 
    'FI' => '+358501111',
    'RU' => '4019900780', 
    'SE' => '+4672345678',
    'UA' => '0123456789',
    'KZ' => '0123456789'  
  }.freeze
```

How I can set some final value for example `'*' => '1234567'` if the other values are not matching?

Comment: `FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE[key] || FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE['*']`?

Comment: Your last sentence is confusing. I suggest something like, "I would like `FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE[k]` to return a specified "default value" (say, `1234567'`) if the hash does not have a key equal to `k`? How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE = Hash.new('1234567').merge({ 
    'FI' => '+358501111',
    'RU' => '4019900780', 
    'SE' => '+4672345678',
    'UA' => '0123456789',
    'KZ' => '0123456789'  
  }).freeze
```

But simple

```
DEFAULT = "1234567".freeze
FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE["FI"] || DEFAULT
#=> "+358501111"
FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE["??"] || DEFAULT
#=> "1234567"
```

Looks also nice

Comment: Good one, since `FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE` is freezed

Comment: Almost as nice as your eyeglasses. Is `DEFAULT = "1234567".freeze` different than `DEFAULT = "1234567"`? In both cases  the value of `DEFAULT` can be changed, in which case the same warning message is issued.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you can't modify frozen objects in Ruby. `DEFAULT = "1234567".freeze` and `DEFAULT = "1234567"` are different in a way that for instance these operations won't work with frozen one: `DEFAULT[0] = "9"` `DEFAULT << "890"` etc. You can't "mutate" frozen object. But you can reassign any variable of course. So you can reassign `DEFAULT` even if its value is frozen. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Hash#default=` to set the default value:

```
hash =  {
    'FI' => '+358501111',
    'RU' => '4019900780', 
    'SE' => '+4672345678',
    'UA' => '0123456789',
    'KZ' => '0123456789'  
  }
hash.default = '1234567'
hash['UK']
#=> '1234567'
```

Comment: hm, `default`, nice

Comment: Yes, but I get `default=': can't modify frozen Hash (RuntimeError)

Comment: just add `hash.freeze` after setting default. I mean first set default, and freeze after.

Answer (score 3):

There are two main ways of dealing with this problem. @llya assigns a default value to the hash, @fl00r applies the default when the hash is evaluated for a non-existing key, causing `nil` to be returned.

llya shows one way of implementing the default value. It is very clear but uses a few lines of code. Two other ways of doing that deserve mention (though I am not suggesting they are in any sense better than how llya has done it).

*Set the default then add the key-value pairs:*

```
hash = Hash.new('1234567').
            merge('FI'=>'+358501111', 'RU'=>'4019900780', 'SE'=>'+4672345678',
                  'UA'=>'0123456789', 'KZ'=>'0123456789').      
            freeze

hash['oh, my']
  #=> "1234567"
```

*Use [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-tap)*

```
hash = { 'FI'=>'+358501111', 'RU'=>'4019900780', 'SE'=>'+4672345678',
         'UA'=>'0123456789', 'KZ'=>'0123456789'
       }.tap { |h| h.default = '1234567' }.
         freeze

hash['oh, my']
  #=> "1234567"
```

A variantof `fl00r`'s `|| DEFALULT` approach, which arguably reads better, is to use [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch):

```
hash = { 'FI'=>'+358501111', 'RU'=>'4019900780', 'SE'=>'+4672345678',
         'UA'=>'0123456789', 'KZ'=>'0123456789' }

DEFAULT = "1234567"

hash.fetch('oh, my', DEFAULT)
  #=> "1234567"
```

`hash[key] || DEFAULT` clearly cannot be used if `hash` has a key whose value may be `nil` or `false`, though that is not an issue here.

Both approaches have pros and cons. Setting a default value avoids the need for the retrieval of values (which may be done in multiple places) to be concerned about whether the hash contains a particular key, but on the other hand readers of those parts of the code may not be aware (or have forgotten) that the hash was defined with a default value.  If the `|| DEFAULT` approach is used there is the possibility that the coder may forget to include `|| DEFAULT` in one or more places where the hash is referenced. In terms of code maintenance I would think it's a toss-up, provided the constant `DEFAULT` is defined in close proximity to the hash, and commented suitably.

It seems to me that it's generally best to use a default value, and wherever the hash is referenced remind readers that it has a default value, either with a comment or a suggestive name for the hash (e.g., `applies_to_oranges_with_default`).